# Bootstrap JS Print the same view

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I want to print my website's view. But when I am printing my website, It's showing this one:

http://alierdemsunar.com/printpage.png

But I want real view's print. Because my real view of my website is this:

http://alierdemsunar.com/realview.png

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap by default has some settings designated for print media, check line 192 in the bootstrap css. Your best bet is to look at these and/or override them to create your own style sheet for print. If you are simply looking to print the full page a single time for your own purposes there are plenty of free tools to snapshot a web page. Check out http://www.shrinktheweb.com/